# Adding + into a PHP string after it is entered into a search form

Tags: php, string, forms, search

probably a simple question however I am not the best at PHP.

I'll show you the code first:

```php
$prodTitle = $_GET['prodName'];

$html = file_get_html('http://www.play.com/Search.html?searchtype=allproducts&searchsource=0&searchstring='.$prodTitle.'');
```

Hopefully you can understand what I am trying to do. In this case **$prodTitle** would be the keyword coming from a text input form. However the problem is that the website I am putting *$prodTitle* into will not accept spaces into its search string.

So if I where to search for *Transformers Box Set* using my search form the search will not work. Currently I have to put in *Transformers+Box+Set* to get it to work.

Is there a way to add in the "+" without having to write it in my search form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix it with `urlencode()` like this:

```
$prodTitle = urlencode($_GET['prodName']);
```

Docs: http://nl.php.net/urlencode

Also, make sure it is safe. Never trust any input from users.

Comment: Great that works, thank you very much! Sorry for late reply have had a busy couple of days!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace any space with a '+' before you add it to the URL.

```
$prodTitle = str_replace(' ', '+', $_GET['prodName']);
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the reply! urlencode seems to do the trick, however this would work as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `urlencode()`:

```
$prodTitle = $_GET['prodName'];
$html = file_get_html('http://www.play.com/Search.html?searchtype=allproducts&searchsource=0&searchstring='.urlencode($prodTitle).'');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is this:

```
$searchTerm = str_replace( ' ', '+', $_GET['prodName'] );
```

https://www.php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$prodTitle = urlencode(htmlspecialchars($_GET['prodName']));
```

And hope it will help